# Equation-reference with cleveref

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, theorems, ntheorem

I am using cleveref, which seems to be working fine, except for my equation references, which are referenced as ??.

My equation is:

```
\begin{equation}\label{ex2eqn}
Y_{t} = \epsilon_t + 1.8Y_{t-1} + 0.8Y_{t-2} + 0.2Y_{t-6} - 0.36Y_{t-7} + 0.16Y_{t-8}
\end{equation}
```

and my reference is

```
This transformation is done by inserting $Y_{t-1}$ into \Cref{ex2eqn}, then $Y_{t-2}$ and so on.
```

A minimal working example is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{ex2eqn}
e=mc^2
\end{equation}
A reference: \Cref{ex2eqn}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I supplement your code snippets to a full example, I can't comprehend the problem. Please provide a [minimal example](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl) that *clearly* reproduces the described behaviour.

Comment: You need to compile twice to have the references set. Did you do that?

Comment: I did. I am sorry I did not supply a minimal working example in the beginning. Now that I have, it seems the problem is rather odd, and has something todo with the combination of thmmarks and amsmath...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load `ntheorem` with the `amsmath` (compatibility) package option.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{ex2eqn}
e=mc^2
\end{equation}
A reference: \Cref{ex2eqn}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I found that loading the `ntheorem` package (without the additional `amsmath` option) before the `amsmath` package also fixed it.

Comment: @cmhughes: I doubt that this won't break other things. See section 3.2.1 of the `ntheorem` manual.